# Detecting when Partial<T> extends T

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a use-case where I'm *building* to a target "state":

```
type State = { foo: number, bar: number, baz?: string };
```

When I start, i most likely haven't achieved the full State but rather am happy to fit into the shape of `Partial<State>`. What I want to be able to do, how is infer when I've reached fabled `State` state.

To help me achieve this goal, I first created a utility type called **Resolve**:

```
type Resolve<T extends Partial<State>> = 
    T extends infer U 
        ? U extends State ? State : Partial<State> 
        : never;
```

This utility works when it is given inferred types like this:

```
const implicit1 = { foo: 5 };
const implicit2 = { foo: 5, bar: 10 };
// YAY: resolves to Partial<State>
const implicitResolve1: Resolve<typeof implicit1> = implicit1;
// YAY: resolves to State
const implicitResolve2: Resolve<typeof implicit2> = implicit2;
```

However, once a type has been expressed as a `Partial<State>` it refuses to infer that it might be of type `State`:

```
const explicit1: Partial<State> = { foo: 5 };
const explicit2: Partial<State> = { foo: 5, bar: 10 };
// YAY: correctly resolves to Partial<State>
const explicitResolve1: Resolve<typeof explicit1> = explicit1;
// SAD FACE: also resolves to Partial<State> even though the intent 
// was for it to be recognized that it is a valid State!
const explicitResolve2: Resolve<typeof explicit2> = explicit2;
```

In my broader solution I had a type guard already waiting in the wings and I figured that would give me the super powers I'd need:

```
type TypeGuard<T> = (thing: unknown) => thing is T;
const tg: TypeGuard<State> = (thing: unknown): thing is State => {
    return typeof thing === "object" 
      && typeof (thing as any)?.foo === "number" 
      && typeof (thing as any)?.bar === "number";
};
function SuperResolve(thing: unknown, tg: TypeGuard<State>) {
    return tg(thing) ? thing as State : thing as Partial<State>
}
// SHOCKED: this resolves to Partial<State> too!
const fnResolve = SuperResolve(explicit2, tg);
```

I'm now at the end of my abilities ... surely there is *some* way to detect when a `Partial<T>` has reached `<T>`.

> [Code Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nr2zlN)

Comment: The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is maybe [Required<T>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype)?

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to be able to get the "actual" type of the value once you've explicitly tagged it with a type. You could have done `const explicit3: Partial<State> = new Date as any` for example.

Comment: @ErikPhilips If I cast a Partial<T> to Required<Partial<T>> in the **Resolve** utility this fails. How had you intended it's use?

Comment: @y2bd not really getting your point ... the `any` assignment is rending the example useless. The intent is to work with a partial structure and as you build it up over time you test to see if it's achieved a "completed" state.

Comment: @ken I didn't have a complete solution, just thought it might help (thus the comment and not an answer)

Comment: @ErikPhilips yeah makes sense ... it was a helpful suggestion but I think it'll be limiting because for optional types on T the `Required` utility will require this to be set as well.

Comment: @ken I believe that once you tell TypeScript the explicit type of a value (in your case by typing the variable), TS "throws away" its own inferred type for the value. This means that you can no longer get at the inferred type of the value and see it as anything beyond `Partial<State>`, similar to when you cast something to `any`, you can no longer see what the original type of the value was (in my case, Date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you annotate a variable to be a single object type like `Partial<State>` (equivalent to `{ foo?: number, bar?: number, baz?: string }`), the TypeScript compiler will not [*narrow*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of the variable upon assigning a more specifically-typed value to it.

Such control-flow-based narrowing only happens to variables/properties of [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) types, and `Partial<State>` is not itself a union type.

So, as soon as you write

```
const x: Partial<State> = { foo: 5, bar: 10 };
```

you have discarded any information the compiler might have had about the particular value you assigned to `x`.  The variable `x` is of type `Partial<State>` no matter what you assign to it.  You could use a user-defined type guard and control flow analysis to *conditionally* narrow it, but this has nothing to do with the actual value assigned to `x`:

```
if (tg(x)) {
    x.bar.toFixed(2); // okay
}
```

---

If you want the compiler to remember that `x` is assignable to `State`, you should not preemptively widen it to `Partial<State>`.  Just let the compiler infer the type of `x`:

```
const x = { foo: 5, bar: 10 }; // okay
```

Anything that requires a `State` or a `Partial<State>` will be happy to accept `x` due to TypeScript's [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system):

```
function takeState(state: State) { }
takeState(x); // okay
```

If you want to ensure that `x` is really a `Partial<State>` upon assignment and not only catch an error later, you could use a helper function like

```
const asPartialState = <T extends Partial<State>>(t: T) => t;
```

And verify that it checks the type of its input against `Partial<State>` without *widening* it to `Partial<State>`:

```
const y = asPartialState({ foo: 5, bar: 10 }); // okay
takeState(y); // okay

const z = asPartialState({ foo: 5, bar: "oops", baz: "" }); // error!
// ------------------------------> ~~~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
```

---

None of this would allow you to do any "building" of a `Partial<State>` into `State`, since the type of a variable does not mutate upon assignments (I don't see any such building in your question either, so I'm not sure if that is in or out of scope.  Assuming it's in scope.)

So, this won't work:

```
const x = { foo: 5 }
x.bar = 10; // error!
takeState(x); // error!

const y: Partial<State> = { foo: 5 }
y.bar = 10; // okay
takeState(y); // error!
```

If you are going to do this building by manually assigning each property, you can use something like an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) instead to get control-flow narrowing:

```
function setProp<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey, V>(
    obj: T, key: K, val: V
): asserts obj is T & Record<K, V> { (obj as any)[key] = val }

const x = { foo: 5 }
setProp(x, "bar", 10); // okay now
takeState(x); // okay
```

If you are hoping to do some more complex or abstract "building" where you loop over properties or pass things to other functions which are not themselves assertion functions, even this will not work:

```
const x = {};
(["foo", "bar"] as const).forEach(k => setProp(x, k, 5));
takeState(x); // error!
```

In such cases, you should just give up on having the compiler try to follow the relatively complicated control flow that proves when your `Partial<State>` has grown into a `State`, and just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it's been done (with possible loss of type safety):

```
takeState(x as State); // no error, but maybe you're wrong
```

or do an unnecessary runtime check with your type guard function:

```
if (!tg(x)) throw new Error("My life is a lie"); 
takeState(x); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHECuBDATgEwDwwHxQF4oAKYACwEsA7AcwC4okqBrKgewHcqBKQ-c6jSgUAzrADcAKEkB6GVADKbALbRWnKlBHAUwCJNCRFOvYSgBvKADM2bBlSTKARhDQAaKE-T3HL955QALwB+Bm00QSgAXylZeRQoQ2gaVExEti0IaAorY11oMhQxFwhNFABjSggANwgMSXK2Km1E+lh4ZHRsBRMIfCJSSloGJnUubgYBWmExHvy+C0koZag0CGAkNE0ktlypoQJDqAAiNicAKwhy4GOoADI7xPhdkn2oIveqEG5ggDobDKHIjHBzOVy3B5PSAvQaRD4oL4-X5eNCEI4g3zgqQxaRUFCqERgCrQABybCM5mkKygjWawCgAA8GAAFdDACgoAA2WDmen6FmstgYAFYPCiGABGAAM0SpKxyrxoxAZ3F4lOp1IZyPQv2AbAAYhQGXViAAmbjiKByKBsZgoEBLFZRaTOyRWJjXChNRIoZgQXkQYjafIMANq2WSPEEonlaAAeTtIEWcuWtJaDLMlgBIrF3ig0uiUmpOj9AeVFqt8lt9pTNKaLSKrLQ7K5AbMOCgEAZeioGDETZb3IDuFwpAYMF4BH4sWpafpSaIjbZHM5ZazQqgooCaElMqiFet1Ydxd9-t6xG+lsPidrc6ggTMS+bK7Xgrsm9zO5OtjAImOucCBhjlufcr3kVw0DYNAAEJHWWa0AFokOQlDULQ9CkPwAA-HC4MrdojAAcnCQRCJmKB2HpIoRAoGg8ScTloD1KFoEI0E-CgAAfRhewgKxqDqQjfhdXF8QgQliSgAAhJAKE5DBBDJClb3rekMyIdd32FWVNW1VEiGlMDOzQSCYLwksz3ycsjIgqDYLwu8QBZZcuR5Xp+U0kUdJWEA9LMQz8KPczTzLS98NsszJFdd0qE9b0RHWZlILADsux7PsbQuK5gA8ABpTtu1KDKkvJVxQFyiAQA8AA1Uc8LOc5xw8P0nKgXKPGqLkGGqyQJneEQEubMQGvImB7igAAlK4oOwdqoFqgViBG+FEQAbRagBdMxOs5CNIzEiTY2k2T5MEBN7WTBzVMZTM3y851qQS4ASrAZUPGOFF-3zKUDyrRMKM4YLS3PFUjKCq66SgVqBxXNz8g8u7N285Ynpei93s+jxpQtIHLL0C9fq0dlOV2iLPCuFAkASqAYdc4coGUWiyHpSioEKWp3jfPDUeS9GTgBL7hRxk9gassLrwu9gOBE-bo0kmS5IU2gejkzklOgSkIfTTMcWpYhVuOAWMfQY4to+OduH+KCAFEKjIYhmAWHnyTeqBmA8IXhZWCyy1B8KTLs2sfZB-q8j0Qn2GM0yxSQellHtFwobYJBCLWKAOEg2hawVYhoOAJUVV4chII4CiIFL62A7QYhjgAWSTTkcmyMQEkbiBjgrXHfcJoKoiAA)

Comment: I do need to _build_ in my broader example so your latter examples really hit the nail on the head. Thanks again for being the smartest TS'er on SO.

Comment: I have posted my own answer, can you have a look and see if you agree? I will keep the chosen answer as yours until I hear you're ok with it.

Comment: @ken I'm not sure how re-annotating the value from `implicit` with `explicit` is an improvement over the similar `asPartialState()` function.  Obviously you are in charge of which answer is chosen, so I don't have much say one way or the other.  Generally I try to make sure my answer has documentation links and can hopefully stand as answers that help future readers as well as the original asker (which is why I went into the "building" part in detail).

Comment: Yes your right, when i tried using this it didn't work as I'd hoped. I will remove my solution as I think it adds limited utility.

Answer (score 0):

`State` is a complete subset of `Partial<State>`, that is why  `State | Partial<State> == Partial<State>`.

The only way you can coerce the `Partial<State>` into `State` is by explicit setting `Required<State>` or, using [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) and setting `SetRequired<Partial<State>, "foo" | "bar">` (but this one implies that you can extract the keys from somewhere).

The following code:

```js
const explicit2: Partial<State> = { foo: 5, bar: 10 };
const explicitResolve2: Resolve<typeof explicit2> = explicit2;
```

is an error because you stripped all the information regarding obligations when you set `: Partial<State>`, it doesn't matter what exists after the `=`.

I suggest you get two Type Guards to assert the types you need. One that can tell if the argument is a `Partial<State>` and another to tell if it is an `State`, and run them in different `if` statements.

Comment: Is there no way to "reduce" the Partial<T> back to an _unknown_ and then use the type guard?